# NPM command for mounteback with nodemon

Tags: npm, nodemon, mountebank

I am using mountebank JS for my mocks and its been a pain to manually restart it.
I have installed nodemon in my package.json and been able to run it but it does not restart when I edited and save the ejs files.
This is the command I have that runs the mountebank via nodemon:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start_mb": "mb restart --configfile mocks/imposters.ejs --allowInjection --allowCORS",
    "start_mb_watch": "nodemon --watch mocks/**/*.ejs --exec \"npm run start_mb\"",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working using this

```
"scripts": {
    "start_mb": "mb restart --configfile mocks/imposters.ejs --allowInjection --allowCORS",
    "start_mb_watch": "nodemon --watch mocks--ext ejs --exec \"npm run start_mb\"",
  },
```